# Filtering an NSMutableArray of objects by starting date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, timestamp, date-range

I'm working on an iOS app and I have an NSMutableArray of objects , objects are events with a starting date and an end date .
The starting date is in a timestamp format , the end date isn't.

I want to filter that array depending on a date that the user will enter (datePicker) .

For now I have this code and it's partially working because let's say that an event will start on 30th of March and ends 2nd of April , if the user will enter any date prior to 30th of March that event will appear on my list (which is ok) but if the user will input let's say 31st of March that same event will not be filtered and that's wrong because the event is till taking place .

```
if(datePickerInTimeStamp>0)
    {
        //I know I might use while instead of an if 
        for (EventObj *_eventObj in eventsList)
        {

            if(_eventObj.dateDebutTimeStamp>0){

                if ( datePickerInTimeStamp <= _eventObj.dateDebutTimeStamp)

                    [self._filteredListCaleventsList addObject:_eventObj];


            }
        }
    }
```

I'm thinking of converting the end date into timestamp and using some sort of range check.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why a filter date before 30th March is OK, given presumably it should be between the start and end date?

Comment: Just as a readability note - it is normal convention to name properties _without_ the underscore (`_`). The underscore is used to denote the ivar backing the property (in the normal case that there is a backing ivar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want the filter to filter, but here's a couple suggestions:

1. Use OO design. Teach your events to indicate if they match.
2. Use NSDate comparison methods earlierDate: and laterDate:

I'll guess from your question that you want to pick events that are occurring at the time of the user-selected date:

```
// in your class EventObj.m

// answer true if date is between the event start and end
- (BOOL)isOccurringOn:(NSDate *)date {
    return [self.start == [self.start earlierDate:date]] &&
           [self.end == [self.end laterDate:date]];
}
```

If you want to filter some other way that would be natural for an event, like starts before, starts after, ends before, etc., BOOL-answering methods here are the way to do it.

Now your EventObj does something that makes sense and is easy to read, and your loop is prettier, too:

```
// get NSDate *selectedDate from user
// using your var names, though the _underscores are strange ...

for (EventObj *_eventObj in eventsList) {
    if ([_eventObj isOccurringOn:selectedDate]) {
        [self._filteredListCaleventsList addObject:_eventObj];
    }
}
```

Comment: `- (BOOL)isOccurringOn:(NSDate *)date {
    return [self dateDebut]== [[ self dateDebut ]earlierDate:date] && [ self dateFin] == [ dateFin laterDate:date];
}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are into one-liners, here is one that does what you are after:

```
self.filteredListCaleventsList = [eventsList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateDebutTimeStamp >= %@", datePickerInTimeStamp]];
```

Notice that it uses a predicate defined on the fly without a variable to hold it. If you think your code is more readable with a variable, you can just define one.

I also took the opportunity to remove the underscore at the beginning of the property name, in line with standard naming conventions. The underscore is used to denote the ivar backing the property (in the normal case that there is a backing ivar).